# JavaFX update a Sqlite table

Tags: java, database, sqlite, javafx

I am currently working on a program the function of which is to store my passwords, and this is why I am using an SQL database called Users. This database contains tables for all the users which will be using the program. Those tables have four columns:

```
SiteName, Username, Password, AdditionalInfo
```

I am having a problem updating a specific row. This is my the code I get an error with:

```
public static void editPassword(String user, String siteEdited, String site, String usernamej, String password, String info){
     try{
         System.out.println(usernamej);
         Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
         c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:res/Users");
         c.setAutoCommit(false);
         stmt = c.createStatement();
         String update = "UPDATE " + user + " set Username = " + usernamej + " where SiteName = " + siteEdited;
         stmt.executeUpdate(update);
         stmt.close();
         c.close();
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.err.print( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
     }
 }
```

It is in a class made specifically for dealing with the sql database and it gets the following error when I try to change the username to 'test':

> java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: test)

Comment: Could you print out the 'update' string before you doe the 'executeUpdate()'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the value you pass in for `user` is the name of the table, your `update` string is going to look like

```
UPDATE usertable SET Username = test where SiteName = siteEditedValue
```

You need to quote the string values:

```
UPDATE usertable SET Username = 'test' where SiteName = 'siteEditedValue'
```

The quick and dirty way is:

```
String update = "UPDATE " + user + " set Username = '" + usernamej + "' where SiteName = '" + siteEdited + "'";
```

However, it's much (much, much) better to use a `PreparedStatement` in this case:

```
public static void editPassword(String user, String siteEdited, String site, String usernamej, String password, String info){
     try{
         System.out.println(usernamej);
         Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
         c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:res/Users");
         stmt = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE " + user + " SET Username = ? Where SiteName = ?");
         stmt.setString(1, usernamej);
         stmt.setString(2, siteEdited);
         stmt.executeUpdate();
         stmt.close();
         c.close();
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.err.print( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
     }
 }
```

This code assumes the type of `stmt` is `PreparedStatement`, not just `Statement`.

As well as taking care of quoting the values for you, this will escape any sql for you, preventing the possibility of SQL-injection attacks (while these are far less of an issue in a desktop application that a web application, it's still a good habit to get into).

Comment: Ok sorry for asking another maybe quite stupid question but it your code in the line :
                   stmt.executeUpdate(update);
the update is never declared..

Comment: @AleksandarDanevski its probably a typo ... the method `executeUpdate` in a `PreparedStatement` doesnt have a argument. so just call `stmt.executeUpdate()`

Comment: @James I tried it both ways and I still get an error: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (Connection is closed)

Comment: @AleksandarDanevski take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998695/java-missing-database-error maybe you find a solution here

Comment: @griFlo yes: thanks for pointing out the typo. Fixed in the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

@griFlo I got it running with this code:

```
 public static void editPassword(String user, String siteEdited, String site, String usernamej, String password, String info){
         try{
             System.out.println(usernamej);
             Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
             c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:res/Users");
             c.setAutoCommit(false);
             PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE " + user + " SET Username = ? Where SiteName = ?");
             stmt.setString(1, usernamej);
             stmt.setString(2, siteEdited);
             stmt.executeUpdate(update);
             c.commit();

         stmt.close();
         c.close();
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.err.print( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
     }
     }
```

I had forgotten to put c.commit();