# Spring boot 1.5.2 Hibernate does not support SQLite3?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sqlite, maven

I've searched lot in the Internet but cannot find a solution to make Spring Hibernate works with SQlite (e.g: this answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/24233241/2028440 told to make a custom SQLite package and it is not ideally, I'd expect to have a .jar file as a dependency from Maven repository for SQL dialect).

I also tried this jar library https://github.com/EnigmaBridge/hibernate4-sqlite-dialect in POM as:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.enigmabridge</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate4-sqlite-dialect.git</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlite:test.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = com.enigmabridge.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
```

However, I got the error when running the web application from Spring boot hibernate

```
Caused by: 

org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [com.enigmabridge.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

If anyone has some suggestions, please help, thanks!

Comment: Can you paste `SQLiteDialect` class?

Comment: Is `SQLiteDialect` class in `com.enigmabridge.hibernate.dialect` package?

Comment: I did not plan to make a class but using jar file only.

Comment: so, having looked at `StrategySelectorImpl`, I suspect `SQLiteDialect` isn't loaded. Can you double check whether this class in your buildpath?

Comment: see my next answer below, thanks.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998695/java-missing-database-error on how to initialize databases in `sqlite`